# Google Cloud Stackdriver Debugging debug inside a for loop at a specific condition?

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am using Google Cloud `Stackdriver Debugging` for both `Compute Engine/App Engine` apps, I am trying to write a condition within a for loop such that when for loop will execute for a certain condition I want to see that data.

My App Engine Code

```
for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
         if (docs[i].country == "India") {
             var city = docs[i].city;
             var lang = docs[i].lang;
         } else {

         }
    }
}
```

Now for above code, I want to see `lang` value when the country value will be `India` and city value is `Bangalore`.

Now as I can add a Snapshot at `var lang = docs[i].lang;` but I want to add breakpoint only for city `Bangalore`.

I tried writing `Condition`

> docs[i].city == "Bangalore"
>
> Error evaluating condition: TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined

Can anyone please tell me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the temp car 'city' as in

city == "Bangalore"

To see 'lang', place the snapshot on the next line, where the 'else' is.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it, can you show me the code to do this?